# How to get button value when event is propagated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am making a react button component and the component looks like this

```
const Button = props => {
  return (
    <button
      style={props.style}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={`btn ${props.color} ${props.loading &&
        "loading"} ${props.block && "block"} ${props.className}`}
      disabled={props.disabled}
      type={props.type}
      value={props.value}
    >
      <span className={"content"}>
        {props.icon && <span className={"icon-left"}>{props.icon}</span>}
        {props.children}
      </span>
      {props.loading ? <Spinner /> : null}
    </button>
  );
};
```

The issue arises when i try to add a value prop and an event listener to the button component.
If i do that and i try getting the `event.target.value` value from the onClick handler, it gets to work only when i click other parts of the button, clicking the span text returns an `undefined`

This seems logical since there is no value on the span, what is the best way i could use to fix this?

Comment: onclick of span can trigger onclick of button

Comment: Add some attribute to the span, set the value of button to that attribute and use: `e.target.getAttribute`

Comment: event.target.value will not return any values for button/span elements, as those elements is not having value attributes in it. So try some thing like  event.target.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`

> The currentTarget event property returns the element whose event
>   listeners triggered the event.

More on reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_currenttarget.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Add an attribute `data-value` to the `span`. So on click get the event.currentTarget.value  or `event.currentTarget.dataset.value`

Inside the handler do like this

```
 let m = event.currentTarget.value? 
         event.currentTarget.value:
         event.currentTarget.dataset.value
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know there was a currentTarget property in the event object